# Is there a way to do Pytorch element wise equality treating each dimension as an element?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors and I want to check for equality treating an array in one dimension as the element

I have 2 tensors

```
lo = torch.Tensor(([1., 1., 0.],
                   [0., 1., 1.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [1., 1., 1.]))
lo = torch.Tensor(([1., 1., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.]))
```

I've tried using
`torch.eq(lee, lo)`
which returns a tensor like

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Is there a way to have the output become

```
tensor([1, 0, 1, 0])
```

as the only complete element that matches is the first?

edit:
I've come up with this solution

```
lee = lee.tolist()
lo = lo.tolist()
out = []
for i, j in enumerate(lee):
  if j == lo[i]:
    out.append(1)
  else:
    out.append(0)
```

and out will be [1, 0, 1, 0]
But is there an easier way?

Comment: take manhattan distance and see what row summs to zero. Moment, i ll write a code. Or take torch.eq(lee, lo) and row must summ to its len , means all 1 must be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `torch.all(tensor, dim)`.

code:

```
l1 = torch.Tensor(([1., 1., 0.],
                   [0., 1., 1.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [1., 1., 1.]))
l2 = torch.Tensor(([1., 1., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.]))
print(torch.eq(l1, l2))
print(torch.all(torch.eq(l1, l2),  dim=0)) # equivalent to dim = -2
print(torch.all(torch.eq(l1, l2),  dim=1)) # equivalent to dim = -1
```

output:

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.uint8)
tensor([0, 0, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)
tensor([1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=torch.uint8) # your desired output
```

Answer (score 1):

Or take torch.eq(lee, lo) and row must summ to its len , means all 1 must be there

```
import torch
lo = torch.Tensor(([1., 1., 0.],
                   [0., 1., 1.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [1., 1., 1.]))
l1 = torch.Tensor(([1., 1., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.],
                   [0., 0., 0.]))


teq = torch.eq(l1, lo) 

print(teq)

tsm =  teq.sum(-1)

print(tsm == 3)
```

tsm  is tensor([3, 1, 3, 0])
printout returns [1, 0, 1, 0]

Comment: That's great! Thank you!

Comment: or you do tsub = torch.abs(lo-l1)

tsm2 =  tsub.sum(-1)

print(tsm2== 0) but the one with eq is main method

Comment: just found a better way, just do tmin = teq.min(-1) , will be 0 for rows where at least one 0 is staying